# Can I control how long can be library loaded in memory?

Tags: .net, iis

I'm working on a web application (IIS, MVC, .NET) and use other libraries (WebGrease, itextsharp...). It does not matter what they are. When you first access the Web application the libraries are loaded into memory and after some time will be unloaded (probably controls GCollector?).

Can I control how long can be library loaded in memory? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it manages by operating system.